# retrieving direct messages twitter api

Tags: php, api, twitter

I want to retrieve direct messages from twitter using TwitterAPIExchange.php. The settings in my application are: write/read and direct messages. What I am missing? Merry Christmas

Updated Code

```
   $settings = array(
  'oauth_access_token' => $accessToken,
  'oauth_access_token_secret' => $accessTokenSecret,
  'consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
  'consumer_secret' => $consumerKeySecret
);
$i = 0;
$cursor = -1;

do {
  $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages.json';
  $getfield = '?cursor='.$cursor.'since_id=240136858829479935&count=1';
  $requestMethod = 'GET';
  $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
  $response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                      ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                      ->performRequest();

  $response = json_decode($response, true);

  if (!empty($response["next_cursor_str"])) {
    $next_cursor = $response["next_cursor_str"];
  } else {
    $next_cursor = 0;
  }

  $errors = $response["errors"];

  if (!empty($errors)) {
    foreach($errors as $error){
      $code = $error['code'];
      $msg = $error['message'];
      echo "<br><br>Error " . $code . ": " . $msg;
    }
    $cursor = 0;
  } else {
      $users = $response['tweets'];
      foreach($users as $user) {
          echo 'tweet:'  .  $user['text'] . '</br>';
      }
  }
  if ($next_cursor != null) {
    $cursor = $next_cursor;
  }
} while ( $cursor != 0);
```

Solved.
Please read this code that could help you.

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php'); 
$settings = array( 
    'oauth_access_token' => "xxx",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxx",
    'consumer_key' => "xxx",
    'consumer_secret' => "xxx");
  $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages.json';
  $getfield = '?since_id=240136858829479935&count=1';
  $requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);

echo "<h3>Mensajer directos</h3>";          
foreach($string as $items)
 {
            $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/show.json?';
            $requestMethod = 'GET';
            $getfields = array('id' => $items['id']);
            $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);           
            $do = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                          ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)                         
                          ->performRequest();
            echo "<strong>Teet:</strong> ".$items['text']."<br />";
            var_dump(json_encode($items, true));
        }
```

Comment: What is the output? Any errors?

Comment: any erro.. you can see it in:http://turpin.es/turpin/direct.php

Comment: I have updated the code with more details

Answer (score 1):

One glaring error in your code I see here is items is not a response object of direct_messages API. It's 'tweets'.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/direct_messages and look for **Response Object**

Assuming your app has taken care of providing necessary permissions to the user of accessing direct messages, can you try modifying your **for** loop as following:

```
...
foreach ( $string ['tweets'] as $items ) {
    echo  $items['text'];
    ?>
```

`$assoc = TRUE` is taking care of converting the object to associative array already. Now you need to iterate over the response objects contained in this array.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I´ve updated the code but I get: Error 32: Could not authenticate you

Comment: sure, that might be because $settings array. Can you check if these parameters are getting set fine - check against the values from your app @ https://dev.twitter.com would help!

$settings = array(
  'oauth_access_token' => $accessToken,
  'oauth_access_token_secret' => $accessTokenSecret,
  'consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
  'consumer_secret' => $consumerKeySecret

Comment: also, please check if the app has write permissions as well. These 2 considerations would resolve your authentication issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks. My permissions are correct and $settings array too. I have revisited it. I´m trying a simple code and I think that there is a problem in the foreach:                                $responses = json_decode($response, true);
if (is_array($responses)){
     $users = $responses['tweets'];
    foreach($responses as $user) {
          echo 'tweet:'  .  $user['text'] . '</br>';
      }
 }